# what are examples of exact cover problems in real world applications?

Tags: algorithm, knuth

In computer science, the exact cover problem is a decision problem to determine if an exact cover exists. The exact cover problem is NP-complete[1] and is one of Karp's 21 NP-complete problems.[2] The exact cover problem is a kind of constraint satisfaction problem.

I have been reading examples of exact cover problems such as the n-queens, sudoku, etc but cant seem to understand how a problem can be exact.

Comment: Exact refers to covering each item exactly once. Your last sentence suggests you interpreted that differently.

Comment: @harold: I thought so too, but in fairness the Wikipedia Exact Cover article mentions those 2 problems as examples (and gives a somewhat convoluted justification that I didn't have the energy to verify).

Comment: see some answers at https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/74407/what-are-the-real-world-applications-of-set-cover-problem